# Event Raise on Service

Tags: android

Think I have a service that play musics , Also I have an actvity that bind to this service , I want when this service started a new music , raise an event and Activity shows a toast , how can I do this , like here

```
Service service = new se...
BindToService();

service.OnMediaPlayerStarted(new Event(

public void run()
{

};
));
```

I want to craete a custom event like MediaPlayerStarted and when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Two ways:

1) Use a LocalBroadcastManager and write a receiver for sending and receiving the Broadcasts within the application (Might be heavy and complex, so not expanding the details, but works).

2) Use Message passing using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) (This is Simple).

- Create a Handler in Main Activity and pass its reference to Service
- Send a Empty Message using the Activity handler with respective event ID and update the UI accordingly in the Activity.
- [Refer to this Example.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) - This user TimerTask and Runnables but for your pupose just send empty Message using the Handler and handle them in handleMessage(Message msg) call back of Handler.